# Undefinable network error - Python Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, http, networking, error-handling, python-telegram-bot

so I'm running a python (python telegram bot) code in my terminal and suddenly receiving network errors without any action on the Bot implied. Curious thing about this is that I have multiple terminals open running different codes (but all pub) and no other code receives this network error leading to the conclusion, that it's not a real network error.

This is the whole error message I'm receiving. It's fairly long so I've put in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/3qehuJNR
`2024-02-21 19:15:23,843 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started`

Mainly it's http errors, badrequest, bad Gateway and unrecognised network.
Hopefully someone can identify more than me. If you need further information let me know.

I tried not much to solve as I do not know where the problem might be and where to start trying solutions to be honest. First time receiving an error like this.

Comment: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/dev-wiki/wiki/Handling-network-errors